# Why are all numbers not represented in Glove?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

Not all numbers are represented in Stanford's word embedding framework 'glove'. Why is that?

For example, the vector representation for '8900' exists, but for '8594' it throws an error.

Comment: Maybe you can answer this yourself. What do you think, why does "word" have a representation, but not "wrdlbrmpft"?

Comment: It's because the corpus it's trained on doesn't contain the particular token.

Comment: @lenz "wrdlbrmpft" is not a lexicon of the English language. The idea behind the question is how to treat numbers using glove when its not possible to train for all numbers. Some method must be there to generate their vectors.

Comment: @alvas Thanks. I also figured that. But, how does then glove treats numbers ? How to approach numbers when processing text using glove?

Comment: I don't think there are different types. It's all just tokens. "wrdlbrmpft" is a token not seen frequently enough in training, as is "8594". It might help to preprocess numbers to be "0", however.

Answer (score 1):

Is it relevant that some numbers are not represented? If it's not, you could just assign all of the the same vector by preprocessing them to the same value before training.